# Clear Screen in PowerShell and Command Line without erasing everything

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, windows-terminal

In using the `clear` command, the screen clears. Totally. I no longer have access to any of the stuff that was previously on the screen at all.

Is there a way to "clear" the screen (i.e. make the prompt go to the top of the screen) without erasing everything that was on the screen?  Ideally I'd like to "clear" the screen but be able to scroll up to see everything else.

I'm using the Windows Terminal program and the PowerShell shell, but I'd like to know the answer for the Windows Command line, too.

I put that I wanted to maintain the ability to scroll up -- by this I mean I want to be able to see everything that came before I hit the "clear" command, so... yes, I want to maintain everything that came before, not the command history.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PSReadline (PowerShell's standard input handler) has the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> hotkey found in most Unix shells, which clears the screen as if you forced all text to scroll out (like the ASCII "Form Feed" character would).

In PS5 though it still erases the *displayed* text fully – but everything that has already gone to the scrollback will remain in the scrollback.

As a workaround, you can output enough empty lines to push everything into scrollback:

```
echo ("`n" * $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height)
```

...and then bring the cursor to top:

```
$e = [char]27
echo "$e[H" # Move cursor to 0;0
echo "$e[J" # Erase down/right
```

This could also be bound to a key using `Set-PSReadlineKeyHandler -ScriptBlock`.

Cmd doesn't have an equivalent – it reads input in line-mode, with only a few shortcuts provided by Conhost instead. However, you can still create a batch script (or even a Conhost DOSKEY alias) which would output the same VT sequences.

Comment: This could work!  I'll give it a shot and let you know.

Comment: CTRL+L works great for PowerShell!  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

While clearing the screen is a *terminal* function (via ANSI terminal control codes), the way that you get those codes sent can be different depending on the shell.  The general idea is that:

- `ESC[2J` clears the screen, but leaves the scrollback
- `ESC[3J` clears the screen, including all scrollback

... where `ESC` represents the ASCII character code 27.

According to `man clear` on Linux, the `2J` code was originally (in 1999) an extension to XTerm, which was picked up by the Linux kernel in 2011 for the console driver.  Sometime later, Windows Console Host picked it up, and it's been in Windows Terminal probably since its inception.

###### Windows Terminal (for all shells)

Windows Terminal includes the [`clearBuffer` action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/actions#clear-buffer) which can be bound to any hotkey.  However, it impacts all shells *regardless of what application may be running inside it*.  For that reason, I recommend against using it unless you are sure you won't accidentally press the hotkey when in something like `vi` (or worse).

That said, it's definitely the easiest way to get this functionality in CMD.

If you do want to use it, the `clearBuffer` action allows you to specify a `clear` target of:

- `screen`
- `scrollback`
- `all`

Using the `screen` option will clear the current contents of the screen but leave the scrollback in place.

You'll need to edit your Windows Terminal `settings.json` directly since the UI doesn't have a way to set the `clear` target:

```json
        {
            "command": 
            {
                "action": "clearBuffer",
                "clear": "screen"
            },
            "keys": ""
        }
```

###### PowerShell

For *PowerShell*, as [user1684 beat me to it](https://superuser.com/a/1738558/1210833) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> sends the proper escape sequence.

On the other hand, `Clear-Host` (alias `clear`) on PowerShell sends a `ESC[3J` (clearing the scrollback as well).

If you have muscle memory in typing `clear` in PowerShell, you could simply change its definition:

```
Remove-Item Alias:clear
function clear {
    Write-Output "$([char]27)[2J"
}
```

Place this in your PowerShell profile if you want it to be permanent.

###### CMD

It's possible, but tricky to do this in CMD as well.

The biggest problem in CMD is actually getting the ESC character (ASCII 27) printed.  I had the actual "character" pasted in here which would transfer via copy/paste to CMD, but it was erased the first time I made another edit to this post.  The character is still there in the (source) edit history for this answer, but let's find a better way to do this.

From *PowerShell*, use this to create a *CMD* batch file:

```
@"
@echo off
echo $([char]27)[2J
"@ | Out-File -FilePath .\clear.cmd -Encoding ASCII
```

Executing the resulting `clear.cmd` batch file in CMD should clear the screen (but not the scrollback).

If you have problems with that, any way you can print an ASCII 27 followed by `[2J` should work.  If you have PowerShell Core installed, for instance:

```
pwsh -c "Write-Output "`e[2J""
```

And just to provide some additional detail on one of your comments:

> That seems like either the world's largest design failure or... I dunno. I maintain that there is probably a workaround at the very least.

So yes, we've come up with a workaround, but it honestly wouldn't surprise me if we hadn't.  Remember, Windows Console Host (in which CMD used to run by default) dates back to Windows 95 (so 27 years now), well before XTerm even added those codes.

And while Windows Terminal is much more modern, I don't think CMD (which needs to generate the codes) has seen any substantial update since before PowerShell was released in 2006.

Really, I count ourselves lucky we've got a workaround ;-).

###### Windows Subsystem for Linux

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> also works from many Linux shells to send a `ESC[2J` (leave scrollback).
- `clear` will act like on PowerShell, clearing the screen *and* scrollback (`ESC[3J`).
- `clear -x` will leave the scrollback (`ESC[2J`)

Answer (score 3):

As a workaround, in CMD you can hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↓ (Down arrow)</kbd> until screen is empty. It will scroll down fairly fast, so it is possible to scroll too much. In that case you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→ (Right arrow)</kbd> or start typing, and the prompt line pops back into view. Anything that moves cursor will do.

This doesn't seem to work in Powershell unfortunately.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I edited answer to make more clear it's cursor key. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @OskarSkog Ah, thanks!  And thanks to user694733 for editing.  Definitely my bad - I even copied and pasted it off to my commandline and it still looked like an "I", but it was definitely a down arrow all along!

Comment: Just another heads-up -- I do see that Ctrl+Down works as "scroll down" in CMD, but it only works in the legacy Windows Console Host.  I do agree that it's a neat workaround there, but it won't work in CMD in Windows Terminal (which is what the OP is using).  While Windows Terminal has a "scrollDown" actioni that you can bind in the settings, it unfortunately won't scroll down beyond the bottom of the screen - it can only scroll down after first scrolling up (into the buffer).

Answer (score 0):

Use for both CMD and PowerShell the clear screen command.

Enter : `cls`

Comment: This still doesn't allow scrollback in Windows Terminal, unfortunately

Comment: @squillman: It allows using upper-arrow to go back. The commands are still in the buffer, just the screen is cleared. After wiping the screen there is nothing to *scroll*.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about maintaining scrollback, not history

Comment: @squillman: "I no longer have access to any of the stuff that was previously on the screen at all." - now he can, with the upper-arrow key.

Comment: Well, not entirely.  Question is about scrolling back to see the previous _output_ (unless I'm just completely misreading it).  You would have to rerun the commands using upper-arrow (ie- replaying history) which is not always going to be possible.

Comment: I want to not erase everything and still be able to clear the screen.

Comment: You can't on CMD.

Comment: The upper arrow key allows me to see previous commands / entries, not output.  For example, let's say I run a build script that has error messages.  The I hit "clear".  I no longer have access to the text generated by the build script (unless I pipe it to a text file, which I don't want to do).

Comment: Really?  "You can't get there from here?"  That seems like either the world's largest design failure or... I dunno.  I maintain that there is probably a workaround at the very least.

Comment: @harrymc I agree with Bob here.  The question explicitly stated *"any of the stuff that was previously on the screen"*, which isn't "history", but all input/output.  It's not possible using `cls` to scrollback to previous output.  Just, as you said, possible to review *input* (prompt/commandline) history via up-arrow.

Comment: Sorry, that was mostly @squillman who was making that point - Didn't read the "who" on every one of the comments ;-), but agree with them.

Answer (score 0):

## Clear PowerShell and preserve scrollback

### PowerShell

I used `Get-Command` to look for cmdlets like `Write-Host` or `Write-Output` because it seems REALLY odd that this isn't a feature of powershell.

```
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet
```

There isn't one , but I noticed `Clear-Host` was absent from the output. In PowerShell, both `clear` and `cls` *alias* `Clear-Host`. I verified:

```
(Get-Command Clear-Host).CmdletBinding
 # False

Get-Command Clear-Host
 # CommandType     Name
 # -----------     ----
 # Function        Clear-Host
```

So I checked the `Definition` and `ScriptBlock` properties, and they're populated with source code. It might be useful to understand how `Clear-Host` works and what we don't like about its implementation.

```
((Get-Command Clear-Host).Definition)
 # $RawUI = $Host.UI.RawUI
 # $RawUI.CursorPosition = @{X=0;Y=0}
 # $RawUI.SetBufferContents(
 #    @{Top = -1; Bottom = -1; Right = -1; Left = -1},
 #    @{Character = ' '; ForegroundColor = $rawui.ForegroundColor; BackgroundColor = $rawui.BackgroundColor})
 # # .Link
 # # https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=<7_dot_3_DOC_LINK>
 # # .ExternalHelp System.Management.Automation.dll-help.xml
```

`Clear-Host` moves the cursor and replaces the buffer contents. **It does not write to standard output**. Knowing its scope, I feel confident replacing the function.

##### Use `Write-Host` to avoid mutating standard output streams.

- ✅ `Write-Host` appears only to developer, cannot be captured.
- ❌ `Write-Output` - appears to everyone and their logger.
- ❌ `echo` - not even PowerShell; alias of `Write-Output`

```
function Invoke-Clear () {
  $e = [char]27
  . Write-Host "$e[2J$e[H" -NoNewline
}
Remove-Alias -Name clear && Set-Alias -Name clear -Value Invoke-Clear
```

The `.` before `Write-Host` is critical.

I'd recommend aliasing `clear` over `cls` because `clear` is a unix standard and it should give you better interop with non-windows programs/machines. Keep `cls` as a windows-only "hard" clear.

##### Persist the custom script

You can save the above script to your `$PROFILE`. You can modify it in any text editor.

```
#> code $PROFILE -n
notepad $PROFILE
```

> `$PROFILE` points to your *current* shell's PowerShell profile script.